# c# with Selenium: element not visible

Tags: c#, unit-testing, selenium

I'm trying to create an automated ui test with `selenium` in `c#`. Here is my code:

```
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
    driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("my_url");
    driver.FindElementById("textBox").Clear();
    driver.FindElementById("textBox").SendKeys("tire");
    driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
    var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
    wait.Until((ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Id("Moto"))));
    driver.FindElementById("Moto").Click();
```

Before using a wait.until, I was getting the exception `ElementNotVisibleException`, but now I'm getting the exception `WebDriverTimeoutException` because the element with the id "Moto" is not visible.

Here is a screenshot of a part of the DOM:

[image]

So why the moto checkbox is not found or is not visible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code (in `Java`) as it is working at my end for the same structure -

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[@for='Moto']")).click();
```

I don't know why it is causing problem to find `<input>` tag by id

Comment: it's not working. I'm still getting an ElementNotVisible exception

Comment: It seems that label for="Moto" it's covering my input and this is why it's not visible

Comment: Please try this, It may help - `WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='nasik']"));
  JavascriptExecutor js =(JavascriptExecutor)driver;
  js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);`

Comment: the last comment gave me the solution. Thanks

Comment: Just be aware that using JSE is not a user scenario. No user can click on an element using Javascript. If you don't care about user scenarios, then you can ignore this comment.

Answer (score 1):

You might need to scroll to the element to make it visible

```
IWebElement moto = driver.FindElement(By.Id("Moto"));

Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.MoveToElement(moto).Perform();

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Id("Moto"))).Click();
```

Comment: it's not working. I'm still getting an WebDriverTimeoutException exception

Comment: @BudaGavril Is there an attribute `style="display:none"` in the checkbox ancestors tree?

Comment: It seems that label for="Moto" it's covering my input and this is why it's not visible